# WordPress: Submit Form Without Refreshing

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, wordpress

I'm currently working on an own WordPress template which has a function in the admin area that can upload a picture. Uploading, moving to a folder and displaying in the admin area works fine, however, I can't manage to delete them.

Below the picture, I'd like to have an input button. When I click it, it should execute a PHP script (deleting the custom field in which the picture's URL is stored) and remove the picture above.

The problem: I want this all to happen dynamically, that means without refreshing the page. I've found this script which does exactly this:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.post('process.php', $("#myform").serialize(), function(data) {
                    $('#results').html(data);
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form name="myform" id="myform" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Delete" />
</form>

<div id="results"></div>
</body>
```

When I click the "Delete" button, the process.php will be executed - in this case just a simple echo which is being displayed in the "results" div container.

I can't make this script work in WordPress. I copied the form and added the jquery.validate.min.js via `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script`. I left out the script's jQuery because WordPress had loaded its own already. And when I replace WordPress' jQuery with the one from the script by deregistering and registering it again, it's not working either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is old, but in case anyone else stumbles across it...

I don't know if there are any other problems, but first problem is that Wordpress doesn't recognize the $ sign by default. Replace all the "$(" with "jQuery(" to make it work in WP.